# List only pointers with xinput

Tags: python, xinput, gtk3

I'm trying to write a GUI tool to restrict a pointer to a specific monitor (e.g. a touchscreen pointer should map onto its own screen and not across the union of all monitors). The tool is in Python (using pygtk).

For the UI, I need to list all the pointers, so you can select the one you mean, and then call `xinput map-to-output pointer_id monitor_id`. If this command is given the id of a non-pointer device, then it raises an error, so I'd like to avoid giving those IDs as options.

The output of `xinput list` looks like this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Cherry USB Optical Mouse Consumer Control id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Cherry USB Optical Mouse                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 04b4:3003 Consumer Control            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 04b4:3003 Mouse                       id=24   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳          WALTOP     Graphics Tablet  Pen (0)      id=26   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=23   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Cherry USB Optical Mouse System Control   id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Cherry USB Optical Mouse Consumer Control id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 04b4:3003 System Control              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 04b4:3003 Consumer Control            id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 04b4:3003 Keyboard                    id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 04b4:3003                             id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳          WALTOP     Graphics Tablet       id=25   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

To build the menu, I need to get the name and id of all pointers (I guess slave pointers, I don't know what would happen if I selected Virtual core pointer). On the one hand, `xinput list --id-only` and `xinput list --name-only` give the exact information I need, except that I need to filter out the ids and names which are not pointers. On the other hand, I could do `xinput list | grep pointer` to get the relevant lines, but the resulting thing does not look very nice to parse (there are extraneous brackets and the weird ↳ arrow character). I tried looking for options in `man xinput` to either do some filtering or to simplify the output, but couldn't find anything.

My project is based off [ptxconf](http://wenhsinjen.github.io/ptxconf/), and their solution is as follows. I'm hoping to find something more elegant.

```
    def getPenTouchIds(self):
        """Returns a list of input id/name pairs for all available pen/tablet xinput devices"""
        retval = subprocess.Popen("xinput list", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()

        ids = {}
        for line in retval.split("]"):
            if "pointer" in line.lower() and "master" not in line.lower():
                id = int(line.split("id=")[1].split("[")[0].strip())
                name = line.split("id=")[0].split("\xb3",1)[1].strip()
                if self.getPointerDeviceMode(id) == "absolute":
                    ids[name+"(%d)"%id]={"id":id}
        return ids
```

Comment: Thanks. I had not realised that fixing my touchscreen (that I don't use), was so easy. I will add an answer to your filtering question.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor No problem, glad it helped you! In case you're interested, the tool I'm writing is based off an existing one named [ptxconf](http://wenhsinjen.github.io/ptxconf/). It appears to depend on python 2, so I'm simply trying to update it so it'll run on my system.

Comment: How did the old tool do it?

Comment: They parsed the output of `xinput list` in python, but I didn't find it very easy to read so was hoping to take advantage of the `--id-only` and `--name-only` options to get something cleaner. i'll get the snippet and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can not find an answer within `xinput` though not spent much time (I assume that you looked here a lot.

So I went with `awk` is seems like a simple line based with context problem.

```
xinput list | awk 'BEGIN {is_pt=0}; /Virtual core pointer/ {is_pt=1}; /Virtual core keyboard/ {is_pt=0}; {if (is_pt==1) {print $0}} '
```

or with better formatting:

```
xinput list | awk '
  BEGIN {is_pt=0} 
  /Virtual core pointer/  {is_pt=1} 
  /Virtual core keyboard/ {is_pt=0} 
  { 
    if (is_pt==1) {
      print $0
    }
  }
'
```

Each block of code (`{}`) is executed if the proceeding pattern matches. There is one block (the one with the `if` in it, that has no proceeding pattern. It is run for every line. `$0` means all of the current record (line). `BEGIN` is the start of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems to be very similar to the output of `xinput list | grep pointer` - is it straightforward to extract the name and id from the lines there?

It would be easy if `xinput` have the output in simple columns, since then something like `cut` could extract them. I think grabbing something like the regex `/id=[[:digit]]+/` would work for the ID, but I can't see a clean way to get the name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to match my mouse in the xinput list, I'm used to work with sed for these kind of problems so here's the sed based approach:

```
MOUSE_G903_ID=$(xinput --list | sed -rn '/^.*Virtual core pointer/,/^.*Virtual core keyboard/ s/^.*Logitech G903 LS[[:blank:]]+id=([[:digit:]]+).*/\1/p')
```

The -n switch makes sed to supress all output, so you have to print what you want explicitly with the p command, or in this case, the p flag of the s command.

There is a single sed expression (in single quotes) that first defines a range where to operate: the range of lines between the two "header lines" (Virtual core pointer, Virtual core keyboard).

After the range, an s command matches the line that corresponds to my mouse, captures the numeric id and prints it.